# Update field value of a table with max value of two fields of two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-query

I have some data tables with the below schema

```
DeviceStatuses Table
id, Last_Comm, Device_Id
00001, 2020-10-23, DEV1
00002, 2020-09-23, DEV2

RcptStatuses Table
id, Last_Comm, Source
R0001, 2020-10-25, DEV1
R0002, 2020-09-25, DEV2
R0003, 2020-10-30, DEV1

ReceivedTrans Table
id, Last_Comm, Source
R0001, 2020-10-25, DEV1
R0002, 2020-09-25, DEV2
R0003, 2020-10-31, DEV1
```

I need to update "DeviceStatuses" Table's "Last_Comm" field value with whatever the greatest(max) value in the "RcptStatuses Table's Last_Comm" field value and "ReceivedTrans Table's Last_Comm" field value. Due to some limitations, i have to use a single query to do this.

These are the expected output

```
DeviceStatuses Table (After update)
id, Last_Comm, Device_Id
00001, 2020-10-31, DEV1 (max value for DEV1 Last_Comm from RcptStatus and RecievedTx Table)
00002, 2020-09-25, DEV2 (max value for DEV2 Last_Comm from RcptStatus and RecievedTx Table)
```

And i tried this

```
UPDATE DeviceStatuses SET Last_Comm = 
(SELECT MAX(lst) FROM (SELECT rsns.Last_Commu AS lst FROM RcptStatuses rsns , DeviceStatuses WHERE Device_Id = rsns.Source 
UNION ALL 
SELECT rtns.Last_Comm AS lst FROM ReceivedTrans rtns, DeviceStatuses WHERE Device_Id = rtns.Source ) As T) 
WHERE 
(SELECT MAX(lst) FROM (SELECT rsns.Last_Comm AS lst FROM RcptStatuses rsns, DeviceStatuses WHERE Device_Id = rsns.Source 
UNION ALL 
SELECT rtns.Last_Comm AS lst FROM ReceivedTrans rtns , DeviceStatuses WHERE Device_Id = rtns.Source ) AS T ) > Last_Comm
```

But that leads to update a same time (lastCom of device 001) to all devices.

Other things to consider:-

- DeviceId and Source are not unique (may repeat in a table)
- Updation of the DeviceId is only needed if the DeviceId value of the DeviceStatuses table is Less than Max value of other table's or if the DeviceId field value is NULL
- Database driver is MySQL

Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: based on your data sample you should add  also the expected  result

Comment: hello @scaisEdge and Strawberry, sorry about that. I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not clear which column you want updated  (last_comm or device_ID )  anyway if you want update last_comm for corresponding device_id  you could try using an Update based on join for the max result

```
UPDATE DeviceStatuses d
INNER JOIN  (
    select source, max(Last_Comm ) max_last_comm
    from (
    select source, Last_Comm
    from  RcptStatuses
    UNION 
    select source, Last_Comm
    from  ReceivedTrans
    ) t
    group by source 
) t2 ON d.Device_Id = t2.source
SET d.Last_Comm =  t2.max_last_comm
```

Comment: Hey Thanks man. This works. Actually i had to do some editing to make it work to my scenario. But, one problem came up. I'm using mysql and this error pops up

Comment: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Source' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Any idea? This worked on maria DB. But in our system we have to use MySQL, and i can't disable only_full_group_by mode :/.

Comment: @KavindaJayakody  .. answer updated (missed  union in subquery)   .. the code in my sample is ok for full_group_by_mode so .. ..eventually update  your question and add  the code you are actually using

Comment: yeah i actually added GROUP BY and MAX aggregator to inner queries as well (it's not actually needed), and that's why that error pops up. Now it's fixed. Thanks a lot for the help man :). I'll mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the `MAX(Last_Comm)` from the other tables. Just join to *every row* in the other tables, and bump up the `Last_Comm` to the greatest value among them. It'll do this row by row, but by the end, the `DeviceStatuses.Last_Comm` will have the greatest value.

```
UPDATE DeviceStatuses AS d
JOIN RcptStatuses AS rs ON d.Device_ID = rs.Source
JOIN ReceivedTrans AS rt ON d.Device_ID = rt.Source
SET d.Last_Comm = GREATEST(d.Last_Comm, rs.Last_Comm, rt.Last_Comm)
```

But if `DeviceStatuses.Device_ID` is NULL, I don't know how you expect to match it to any rows in the other tables.

Comment: The thing is we have NULL values in our dataset. For using GREATEST is not possible. Thanks for the suggestion btw @Bill

Comment: Please update your question with an example of what you want the result of the update to be (as scaisEdge requested in a comment). Include an example of what you want the result to be for a row where Device_ID is NULL.